# Xcode seems to "jump" lines during execution

Tags: swift, http, debugging, get

I've been struggling for a while with the following swift 4 code : it appears that during the execution (or debug), the lines *89* to *102* are not executed, as if it was some comments... Hence, my array of data is empty so I can't deserialized and use them. Any ideas about why it behaves like that ? Hope my question is pertinent... Thanks :)

[image: Code with line numbers]

Comment: You should include your code as text so that users don't need to click a link to help you. you have a guard statement there so I would guess either data is nil or error is not. Also you are trying to return before the async function would complete.

Comment: `URLSession.dataTask` is asynchronous, hence your "issue". This is the expected behaviour, since the completion handler is only called once the network request returns asynchronously.

Comment: Ok thx guys ! Since it's asynchronous, how can i wait ? 

Should i delete my post since the question doesn't seem pertinent ?